# Make an image dynamically appear in FLASH

Tags: actionscript, flash

I'm new to flash, but I have drag and drop code for my movieclips and so can manipulate them in this way. But I would like to be able to display an image depending on where the user clicks on the movie scene. What would the code be that loads an image, onClick, at the mouse X and Y? Thanks

Comment: Alternatively, using my drag and drop algorithm, keeping the original movie clip in its place and leaving an image of the movieclip where it was "dropped" would be just as useful..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm mainly a Flex developer but this code snippet of AS3 should work fine for you in Flash as well:

```
addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,myMouseHandler);

private function myMouseHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    var swfLoader:SWFLoader=new SWFLoader();
    swfLoader.source="http://www.google.com/images/logos/ps_logo2.png";
    swfLoader.x=mouseX;
    swfLoader.y=mouseY;
    addChild(swfLoader); //note in flex 4 adding to container need to use addElement otherwise this code executes in there fine as well.
}
```

The documentation for AS3 is pretty thorough and can be found here: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/index.html
they did a good job with this version of the documentation of giving you filters at the top of the page to see only items available in Flash only or using a Flex framework or using AIR.  A quick breakdown of how all this relates: AS3 is the scripting language used to write code that gets compiled into what's known as AS3 bytecode (typically all in a file with a swf or swc extension) which is then interpreted by the Flash plugin in the browser.  MXML is a "declarative markup language" it's very similar in appearance to HTML using tags and nesting to represent relationships of parent/child (they are both loosely XML), the MXML gets compiled to AS3 then to AS3 bytecode and once again interpreted by the flash plugin.  Nice thing about Flex is there's a whole lot of pre-built components provided and the framework creates a robust set of rules for how you can create extensible components with a well defined life cycle (you know it gets created once, you know only to update the parts that require updating ie createChildren, commitProperties, measure etc.).  AIR is adobe integrated run-time which is basically a flash player for the desktop where it can live outside the browser and is therefore not limited to the functionality allowed by the browser (due to security issues lots of operations are blocked by the browser), basically AIR is Flex+Desktop related goodies.  I know this is more than what your asking for but I hope you find this info useful.

Good luck,

Shaun

Comment: I believe SWFLoader is only available in Flex. In non-Flex ActionScript, you would normally use a Loader, as in Matt McDonald's example.

Comment: @Lars Ugh, should heed my own advice here and use the filters on the documentation page, thanks for the follow up.  Hope this all was somewhat useful anyhow.

Comment: No problem Shaun, the link and info on the docs where helpful, if not the SWFLoader stuff. But Luke, don't you think it would be more appropriate if you would set Matt's answer as the accepted answer instead?

Comment: I up-voted on @Matt's since it is more the answer to the question at hand but will leave my post for the sake of whatever it added.  Really just want to say thanks to all you guys for being so friendly about me posting something incorrect here, the SO community can be a rather harsh unforgiving environment.  This coming from a person living on the west side of Chicago :).  I greatly appreciate pushing an answer that requires qualification to be qualified, rather than dismissed as "dumb" or "incompetent" as was the case in another thread I was just reading (~47 bashing comments back and forth).

Answer (score 2):

The code you're looking for differs a little bit from the other answer.

```
import flash.display.Loader;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.net.URLRequest;

var loader:Loader;
var toLoad:URLRequest;

stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, clicked, false, 0, true);

function clicked(evt:MouseEvent):void
{
    //if loader already exists, remove it from stage
    if(loader)
    {
        removeChild(loader);
    }
    loader = new Loader();
    toLoad = new URLRequest("image.png");
    loader.load(toLoad);
    addChild(loader);
    //listen for when load completes
    loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, loadCompleted, false, 0, true);
}

function loadCompleted(evt:Event):void
{
    //center to mouse position
    loader.x = (mouseX - (loader.contentLoaderInfo.width)/2);
    loader.y = (mouseY - (loader.contentLoaderInfo.height)/2);
}
```